# Can I call the fortran log function with a number?

Tags: fortran, gfortran

I'm getting some strange results from the log function in gfortran 4.5 (OSX) and gfortran 4.7 (OSX).

The following program gives the unexpected results:

```
program test_log
  real(8) :: e = 2.7182818284590451_8
  write(*,*) 'log(2.7..)', log(2.7182818284590451_8)
  write(*,*) 'log(e)', log(e)
end program test_log
```

I run it like this:

```
gfortran-mp-4.5 ./test.f90  && ./a.out 
log(2.7..)   1.6249753165355076     
log(e)   1.0000000000000000
```

I expected both to be 1.0

*Update:*

```
program test_log
  real(8) :: e = 2.7182818284590451_8
  real(8) :: e2 = 2.7182818284590451D0
  real(8) :: e3 = exp(1.0)
  write(*,*) 'log(2.7..)', log(2.7182818284590451_8)
  write(*,*) 'log(e)', log(e)
  write(*,*) 'log(e2)', log(e2)
  write(*,*) 'log(e3)', log(e3)
end program test_log
```

gives

```
gfortran-mp-4.5 ./test.f90  && ./a.out 
 log(2.7..)   1.6249753165355076     
 log(e)   1.0000000000000000     
 log(e2)   1.0000000000000000     
 log(e3)   1.0188423211430429
```

Comment: your original code gives me both 1.0, I'm on a debian6.0 system running gfortran w/gcc=4.6.1

Comment: and what happens when you change `e` to `2.7182818284590451D0` and/or to `exp(1.0)`?

Comment: If I call `p (double) log((double)2.71828)` while debugging, I do get 1.0.

Comment: the results for all `e`, `e2`, and `e3` make sense, and I assume you'll get exactly `1.0` if you define `e3` as `e3 = exp(1.0D0)`.

Comment: `e3 = exp(1.0D0)` gives `1.01884..`. `write(*,*) exp(1.0D0)` gives   `2.769986...`. Both a bit off.

Comment: and maybe change `exp` to `dexp`, and `log` to `dlog`? or try my answer below.

Comment: I also got the same results with dlog, I reported the issue in the macports build: http://trac.macports.org/ticket/34535 .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
program test_log
  integer, parameter :: Dbl_K = selected_real_kind (14)
  real(Dbl_K) :: e = 2.7182818284590451_Dbl_K
  real(Dbl_K) :: e2 = 2.7182818284590451D0
  real(Dbl_K) :: e3 = exp(1.0)
  real(Dbl_K) :: e4 = exp(1.0_Dbl_K)
  write(*,*) 'log(2.7..)', log(2.7182818284590451_Dbl_K)
  write(*,*) 'log(e)', log(e)
  write(*,*) 'log(e2)', log(e2)
  write(*,*) 'log(e3)', log(e3)
  write(*,*) 'log(e4)', log(e4)
end program test_log
```

Uses selected_real_kind instead of relying on 8 being the value for double.

Output with gfortran 4.6 and 4.7 on a MacBook Pro with Snow Leopard is:

```
 log(2.7..)   1.0000000000000000     
 log(e)   1.0000000000000000     
 log(e2)   1.0000000000000000     
 log(e3)  0.99999996963214000     
 log(e4)   1.0000000000000000
```

The value for e3 is different from 1 because "exp(1.0)" has 1 as a single precision real.

On my new Mac Air with Lion I get incorrect results.   I have observed other problems gfortran on this machine.

gfortran 4.6

```
 log(2.7..)   1.6249753165355076     
 log(e)   1.6249753165355076     
 log(e2)   1.6249753165355076     
 log(e3)   1.6438056251294211     
 log(e4)   1.6438055841322456
```

gfortran 4.7

```
log(2.7..)   1.6249753165355076     
 log(e)   1.0000000000000000     
 log(e2)   1.0000000000000000     
 log(e3)   1.0188423211430429     
 log(e4)   1.0188422801197137
```

So the problem isn't unique.   Not sure what it is.

P.S.  On the MacAir compiler options change the output. I'm not sure which option or options matter.

P.P.S.

```
program test2_log
  real:: e = 2.7182818284590451
  real:: e2 = 2.7182818284590451D0
  real:: e3 = exp(1.0)
  real:: e4 = exp(1.0)
  write(*,*) 'log(2.7..)', log(2.7182818284590451)
  write(*,*) 'log(e)', log(e)
  write(*,*) 'log(e2)', log(e2)
  write(*,*) 'log(e3)', log(e3)
  write(*,*) 'log(e4)', log(e4)
end program test2_log
```

On the MacAir, gfortran 4.6 gives:

```
 log(2.7..)   1.3489696    
 log(e)  0.99999994    
 log(e2)  0.99999994    
 log(e3)   1.0188423    
 log(e4)   1.0188423
```

with the compiler option -fdefault-real-8 it changes to

```
 log(2.7..)   1.6249753165355076     
 log(e)   1.0000000000000000     
 log(e2)   1.0000000000000000     
 log(e3)   1.0188422801197137     
 log(e4)   1.0188422801197137
```

It's some defect in the installation.

Edit: all gfortran versions on both machines are from MacPorts.   Is the different the OS version or something else?   Works on Snow Leopard, not on Lion.

Comment: Where did you obtain the gfortran distribution from? [HPC for Mac OS X](http://hpc.sourceforge.net)?

Comment: MacPorts.   I had a really bad experience with HPC for Mac OS.  At least formerly it put gcc libs in /usr/local.   Mac OS links against that area and having non-system gcc libs there can wreck the OS in a system upgrade.

Comment: I also have the macports version of gfortran. I'll try and find out what's up with it.

Comment: I also noticed the problem since I switched to lion. I'm rebuilding gcc from source to do some more checks.

Comment: I managed to solve this by recompiling gmp using gcc (4.5) instead of clang. Clang is the default compiler for gmp. Using the tests in mpfr and the above test cases I was able to confirm that this issue was solved.

Answer (score 1):

first, try change `exp` to `dexp`, and `log` to `dlog`?

if it's just a problem of your compiler didn't force double precision consistently within the code, so try to force double precision as compiler flag in gfortran: `gfortran -fdefault-real-8 foo.f90`

or by putting in the macro

```
#define REAL DOUBLE PRECISION
```

Comment: Be careful with things like -fdefault-real-8, or the macro version therof.  It breaks stuff.  If you call libraries expecting reals, or you have old code with equivalences, things will break and the reasons won't be clear.   Better to just keep track of what is real and what is double.

Comment: @JonathanDursi indeed, but in OP's case where he/she simply wants to find out the reason for the floating arithmetic exceptions. THat's why I suggest him/her firstly to switch all the declarations and arithmetic into double precision uniformly.

Comment: The compiler is supposed to pick the correct `LOG` intrinsic based on the type of its argument. Looks like compiler bug to me.

Comment: The -fdefault-real-8idea is a workaround for a compiler bug.  And it doesn't work on my Mac Air.   See my answer.

Comment: Thanks, I tried the dlog and the compiler option but without luck.

Answer (score -2):

I'm pretty sure you keep on just calling the natural log. Log() in fortran is used intrinsically for natural.